# To show that a polynomial has no rational roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given a monic polynomial $P(x) = x^n + a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots a_n$, with integer coefficients, I need to show that it has no rational roots (in this case integer) using the following facts

1) $ n>1,$

2) $ a_n=17, $

3) $1+a_1+\ldots+a_n \neq 0$, $1-a_1+a_2 \ldots +(-1)^na_n \neq 0$,

4) $|a_m| \leq 15$,     $  \forall m <n$.

Using the rational root theorem and the first 3 conditions, I was able to rule out $\pm 1$ as roots among the four possible roots $\pm 1, \pm17$. It is clear that I have to use the last condition to rule out $\pm 17$, but I am unable to do that. I may be missing something simple here, but any hints are welcome.

Comment: Try using the finite geometric series.

Comment: @Integrand Thanks, you mean plug in 17 and look at the series. But I only have a bound on the other coefficients, how do I get that to work?

Comment: __Hint:__ $17^n  \geq 15 \times17^{n-1} + 15 \times 17^{n-2} + \ldots + 15\times 17 + 17 $.

Comment: @CalvinLin So, the sum is strictly positive and this rules out 17 as a root, I think condition 3 is also required here to conclude. Did I pick up on your hint correctly?

Comment: @Integrand : How does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P$ is monic and $a_n=17$, we have
$$
P(17) = 17^n + a_1 17^{n-1}+a_2 17^{n-2}+\ldots +a_{n-1}17+17
$$Now use the fact that $|a_m|\leq 15$ for $1\leq m\leq n-1$:
$$
|a_1 17^{n-1}+a_2 17^{n-2}+\ldots +a_{n-1}17+17| 
$$
$$\leq |a_1| 17^{n-1}+|a_2| 17^{n-2}+\ldots +|a_{n-1}|17+17
$$
$$
\leq 15(17^{n-1}+17^{n-2}+\ldots +17)+17 
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{16} \left(17+15\cdot 17^n\right) < 17^n
$$In other words, $|P(17)|$ is strictly greater than $0$, and a similar argument holds for $|P(-17)|$.